# Using .wav files works fine in DAW while using converted .mp3 files doesn't

Tags: mp3, wav, ffmpeg

I am working on Arch Linux and am trying to create an intro movie for my Youtube channel. The idea is to play "**intro.mp3**" which is played only once and then "**loop.mp3**" which will be playing on low volume in the background for like ten minutes or so.

So in order to do this I took a "**song.mp3**" and checked it's metadata with `mediainfo` terminal command:

```
General
Complete name                            : song.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 2.78 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 12 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 320 kb/s
Album                                    : Images And Words
Track name                               : Learning To Live
Track name/Position                      : 08
Performer                                : Dream Theater
Genre                                    : Progressive Metal
Recorded date                            : 1992
Writing library                          : LAME3.98r
FMPS_Rating                              : 1
FMPS_Playcount                           : 3
FMPS_Rating_Amarok_Score                 : 0.5325

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Duration                                 : 1 min 12 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 320 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 2.78 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.98r
Encoding settings                        : -m m -V 10 -q 0
```

After this I started JACK audio server with settings set like this (note the sample rate **44100** is the same as for the "**song.mp3**"):

[image]
[image]

And then Bitwig studio which I used to split the "**song.mp3**" into two separate files "**intro.wav**" and "**loop-x5.wav**" (Bitwig only exports in wav) and in **32 bit depth**:

[image]

Now if I check media details with `mediainfo` terminal command I get:

```
General
Complete name                            : loop-x5.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 13.8 MiB
Duration                                 : 40 s 909 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 2 822 kb/s

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format profile                           : Float
Codec ID                                 : 3
Codec ID/Hint                            : IEEE 
Duration                                 : 40 s 909 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 2 822 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Stream size                              : 13.8 MiB (100%)
```

and

```
General                                                                                                                                 
Complete name                            : intro.wav                                                                                    
Format                                   : Wave                                                                                         
File size                                : 5.52 MiB                                                                                     
Duration                                 : 16 s 397 ms                                                                                  
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant                                                                                     
Overall bit rate                         : 2 823 kb/s                                                                                   

Audio                                                                                                                                   
Format                                   : PCM                                                                                          
Format profile                           : Float                                                                                        
Codec ID                                 : 3                                                                                            
Codec ID/Hint                            : IEEE                                                                                         
Duration                                 : 16 s 397 ms                                                                                  
Bit rate mode                            : Constant                                                                                     
Bit rate                                 : 2 822 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Stream size                              : 5.52 MiB (100%)
```

Which looks completely fine to me and if I import these files back into Bitwig files are played at the **same speed**. Things change if I use FFMPEG to convert files into **mp3** format like this:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.wav -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3 intro.mp3
ffmpeg -i loop-x5.wav -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3 loop-x5.mp3
```

Now if I import **mp3** files back into Bitwig they are out of sync. One plays faster than the other. Why? Here is also the info about **mp3** files:

```
General
Complete name                            : intro.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 257 KiB
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Writing library                          : Lavf57.41.100

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Mode extension                           : MS Stereo
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 257 KiB (100%)
```

and

```
General
Complete name                            : loop-x5.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 640 KiB
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Writing library                          : Lavf57.41.100

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Mode extension                           : MS Stereo
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 640 KiB (100%)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried exporting the .wavs from Bitwig as 24-bit? It may be that for some reason the the 32 bit-depth(float) upsets the FFMPEG conversion.

Comment: I did try to export using Bitwig in 32-bit and 24-bit and in either cases I am getting out-of-sync audios...